# Promiscous mode on vmware workstation

Tags: vmware-workstation, openstack, vswitch

I am trying to do the network setup in the openstack configuration on 3 Ubuntu vm with vmware workstation, but in order to work I get the following indication : If you are building your OpenStack nodes as virtual machines, you must configure the hypervisor to permit promiscuous mode on the external network.

I know that with vcenter I can configure the vswitch in promiscous mode but how can i do this with workstation ? or is it an option in ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1):

## 1.Enable promiscuous mode vmware

If you want all users to be able to set the virtual Ethernet adapter (/dev/vmnet0 in our example) to promiscuous mode, run the following command on the host operating system as root:

## chmod a+rw /dev/vmnet*

To grant selected other users read and write access to the VMnet device, you can create a new group, add the appropriate users to the group and grant that group read and write access to the appropriate device. You must make these changes on the host operating system as root (su -). For example, you can enter the following commands:

## chgrp (newgroup) /dev/vmnet0

## chmod g+rw /dev/vmnet0

Comment: my host is a windows ... any solution for that ?